# XMPP Getting Room Configuration Change Messages While Offline

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

We are using XMPPFramework for IOS to implement chat functions to our mobile applications.
We've changing the room name functionality and when an admin changes the room name, server sends  message to all group receipants, when all the receipants are online there is no problem however when a user is not joined to group(not connected at that time) he is not able to receive the message even when he is back and online again.

We are using history parameter to retrieve old messages in group, but  we cannot receive these configuration changes (and also the information of users added or banned from server) messages.
Do you know how can we solve that?

```
NSXMLElement *history = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"history"];
[history addAttributeWithName:@"seconds" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",disconnetSecond]];
[xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:cusername history:history];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ejabberd, you can use the new MUC/Sub approach and subscribe to configuration changes on node "urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:config".
The specification is described here: https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/xmpp-clients-bots/proposed-extensions/muc-sub/
You would have to add support in XMPPFramework as it is not yet supported, but that should do what you need. You could be able to place in your offline store the configuration changes.

Comment: I've already added the functionality to subscribe for mucsub. However only join and leave presence messages are received from mucsub not configuration messages

Comment: You need to subscribe to the node: urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:config

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Room Subject](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#enter-subject) as room name then it's automatically supported in XMPP. Also [changing room subject](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#subject-mod) is supported and it's sent to a user when he joins room. So ultimately whenever you will join the room, you will get updated subject and you can show it on the UI or even you can show to user that name has been changed.

You just need to follow the directions as defined in [XEP-0045: Multi-User Chat](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html)

Comment: no I'm using the actual room name from room configuration. Also the same problem exists when somebody banned from group or added to group.
If all members are online in the time of banned user, everyone is informed but if some participants are offline they are not receiving the banned user info even if they fetch the messages since the beggining

Comment: Using room subject can solve your problem. Otherwise, room configuration changes will not be delivered to offline users.

Comment: Lets say we solved the name changing problem with subject but how are we going to solve the banned and added user informations to receive all offline participants

Comment: That's not part of MUC XEP, that's custom requirement. When a user is offline, he is not part of any room. So if at that time, a new user joins room, it's notification will be sent to online users. Also there is no offline message storage for group chat messages. Now if you are using Ejabberd, you should check this implementation: https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/xmpp-clients-bots/proposed-extensions/muc-sub/ there are few features to overcome few limitations of MUC XEP.

Comment: But ejabberd stores groupchat messages somehow. Becuase when I joined to a group with requesting the history of 3 hours messages. It returns me the messages since 3 hours ago, so I can get the messages while I'm offline. Only thing I cant get with the history is  members added and banned messages and also room configuration messages